# golang populate struct field from file

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to developing in golang, so if this is an elementary question I apologize. I didn't see a comparable question already asked; if there is one, please point me to it (thanks).

The full code (at the time of my asking this question, since it's not immutable) is at http://play.golang.org/p/idDp1E-vZo

I've declared a struct with four primitive fields, and I'm reading the values destined for `Node.ipaddr` from a file on the local filesystem (I'm getting the value of `fileName` as a flag at runtime; that code is trimmed out here but is in the link provided above.)

```
type Node struct {
    hostname string
    ipaddr   string
    pstatus  string
    ppid     int
}

file, err := os.Open(fileName)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("error opening %s: %v", fileName, err))
}
```

Because the file is line-delimited, I thought a `bufio.Scanner` would be ideal for reading the data from the file.  Where I am struggling is finding an elegant way to actually pass the data into the struct elements.

I created an array of `Node` elements, and have considered a `map`, but I am not sure how I'd make practical use of it (yet).

```
var nodes []*Node
var nodemap = make(map[string]*Node) //do I even need this?

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading from file:", err)
        os.Exit(3)
    }

    //pass scanner.Text() into Node.ipaddr

}
```

Short of wrapping `scanner.Scan()` in an indexed `for` loop, I'm not at all sure how to proceed.  If I do wrap `scanner.Scan()` in an indexed `for` loop, will the `for` loop be able to handle EOF elegantly -- I guess I'm not sure what the index limit/max comparison value should be in that case.

As always, thanks for any advice that you're willing to offer.

**edit**:  The format of the input file is like this:

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
```

I anticipate approx 150 entries in the file, one IPv4 address per line.

Comment: Do you have control over the file's format? also show an example of the file somewhere if not.

Comment: yes, I have control over the format. Will edit OP to put the current format, but they are IPv4 addresses, one per line.

Comment: Given the current scenario, the easiest thing to do is just scan each line as you are doing and parse the ip using: http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ParseIP, then you can simply assign the result of the parsed value to your Node values as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is the `append` function to add a new node to the slice.

```
nodes = append(nodes, &Node{ipaddr: scanner.Text()})
```

Also, you can have an index on your `for` loop while still having the `scanner.Scan()` as the condition.  This lets the `EOF` be handled elegantly while still allowing you to access that new `Node` if need be.

```
for i := 0; scanner.Scan(); i++ {
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading from file:", err)
        os.Exit(3)
    }

    nodes = append(nodes, &Node{ipaddr: scanner.Text()})
    fmt.Println(nodes[i])
}
```

Full code: http://play.golang.org/p/RvMQp-jgWF

Answer (score 2):

You could use something along the lines of [`this`](http://play.golang.org/p/IAFLrxWCet) :

```
func main() {
    file := strings.NewReader(IPS) //os.Open(fileName)

    var nodes []*Node

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error reading from file:", err)
            os.Exit(3)
        }
        ip := net.ParseIP(scanner.Text())
        if ip != nil {
            nodes = append(nodes, &Node{ipaddr: net.ParseIP(scanner.Text())})
        }

    }
    for _, n := range nodes {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %+v\n", n.ipaddr, n)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution provided that the file contents are always IP addresses. I selected the other answer because I think it will provide a more generic pattern, but I'll also be leveraging what I learn from this solution as well. upvoted for the context; thank you.

Comment: A tip for programming in Go, always try to be specific with your data, it will make your code better, faster and harder to break.

Comment: I agree with @OneOfOne, you don't want to do more generic solutions all the time. One day the file will contain something else and no one will notice for a while or so and you end up with random content in `ipaddr` field due to generic `"ipaddr: scanner.Text()"`. Always validate data and be specific or throw an error. It will save your ass one day :)